# 2- norm 2 and A- norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix. We know that
                       $\Vert x \Vert_2=\sqrt{x^Tx}$ and $\Vert x \Vert_A=\sqrt{x^TAx}$.

Is there any relationship between the $\Vert x \Vert_2$ and $\Vert x \Vert_A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively easy to prove that
$$
\lambda_1 \|x\|_2^2 \le \|x\|_A^2 \le \lambda_n \|x\|_2^2,
$$
where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_n$ are the smallest and largest eigenvalue of $A$. Use the spectral theorem.

These inequalities are sharp. Take $x$ to be an eigenvector to the smallest respectively largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Your answer is completely correct. But are there the numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that 
$\lambda_1<\alpha$ and $\beta<\lambda_n$, and moreover,
$$
\alpha \|x\|_2^2 \le \|x\|_A^2 \le \beta \|x\|_2^2?
$$
In other words, I want to look for a sharper relation.

Comment: @Farid: Take $x$ to be an eigenvector for the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_n$ and you will see that such $\alpha, \beta$ do **not** exist.